# How can I add acceleration to the movement of an object in a game

Tags: mathematics, javascript, linear-algebra, kinematic

Below is the code that I'm using to move an object:

```
let XX = 0
let YY = 0
let maxSpeed = 100;

if(keyDown.w) {
    XX += Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)*moveSpeed;
    YY += -Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180)*moveSpeed;
}
```

I'm trying to implement acceleration in moving.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acceleration is a change in speed over time, so you can implement it by incrementing your movespeed over time.

```
movespeed += acceleration_constant;
```

If you want to limit speed, then you can clamp it like this:

```
movespeed += acceleration_constant;
movespeed = (movespeed < maxSpeed) ? movespeed : maxSpeed;
movespeed = (movespeed > minSpeed) ? movespeed : minSpeed;
```